# Fetch user id on behalf of the non-drupal php

Tags: users

I want simply to provide user id to php application that resides under my files/ folder. It is php that one flash app uses to create xml. This script, in my drupal root folder, works:

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once '/var/www/drupal/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
global $user;
$user_uid= $user->uid;
echo $user_uid;
?>
```

but when i try to include whole script in that php app in my files folder, it fails, with many include type errors.

I am searching for simple solution to provide that app with user id!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy that code/file to another directory, DRUPAL_ROOT will be set to that directory, not that of drupal's... so I'd change up that first define to point to where drupal is and you *should* be all set.

Comment: excellent, could you provide me with an example ? I do not know why i need this line, cause i used absolte path in require_once, but without it, it does not work.

Comment: `getcwd()` returns the current working directory, so, just replace that with your drupal root directory which probably is `/var/www/drupal` from your example.

Answer (score 0):

To those interested, i could not in any way accomplish what i wanted, i ended up by setting the cookie. In page.tpl.php:

```
setcookie("uid", $user->uid,  time()+(60*60*24*30));
```

In php app out of the drupal bootstrap:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) {
$user_uid=$_COOKIE['uid'];
}
```